# Why doesn't Java automatically access the overridden method?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Given two classes, a parent class and a child class:

```
class A {
    private void greet() {
        System.out.println("Class A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public void greet() {
        System.out.println("Class B");
    }
}
```

One has a method called `greet()`, which is `private`, and the other one defines a method with the same name, only that it is `public`. Now, as far as I know, the child's `greet()` method doesn't override the parent's method, because it 'hides' it? (given the fact that private methods can't be overridden?)

Now, given the following class and method (considered to be in the same package as `A` and `B`):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.greet();
    }
}
```

This should compile. But this one:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        b.greet();
    }
}
```

This one up here doesn't compile, because it's missing a typecast.
My question would be: why? If the `greet()` method was `public` in both places, it would have shown `Class B` both times. I'm pretty confused about why Java doesn't figure at runtime, for the second case, that `a` is actually referencing to an object of type `B`, and directly calls the method from class `B`.

Tried reading more about polymorphism in an OCA-preparation book, but the authors didn't seem to be so specific about it.

Comment: "Now, as far as I know, the child's greet() method doesn't override the parent's method, because it 'hides' it? (given the fact that private methods can't be overridden?)" Your understanding is correct. And the second `Main` doesn't compile because `A.greet` is `private`.

Comment: Essentially you have told Java to treat B as if it was an A, so it does and finds that it cannot access greet. If you want it to be treated as a B then you have to explicitly tell it to (by casting).

Comment: Since you understand that there is no overriding going on, what exactly do you still not understand?

Comment: @Sweeper Wasn't really sure why the program doesn't compile, but now I realized it has nothing to do with the runtime, but with the compiler. Even if runtime would figure out it is an object of type `B`, the compiler doesn't, so it just fails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your snippet that doesn't compile, the compiler sees that the compile time type of `a` is class `A`.
Therefore, it will only allow you to call accessible methods of class `A` (or of super-classes of `A`). `greet` is a `private` method of `A`, and therefore not accessible. Therefore the compiler doesn't allow calling it.

The fact that the runtime type of `a` would be class `B`, which has an accessible `greet` method, makes no difference, since the compiler doesn't try to figure out what the runtime type of a variable would be.

Comment: That seems to make a lot of sense. So everything's analyzed at runtime, but it can't pass the compiler because the compiler doesn't care what object it references to, only that it is an object of type `A`

Comment: @MarioMateaș No, not everything is analysed at runtime. Method dispatch happens at runtime based on the actual type of the *object*, but the compiler will check if methods exist and are accessible on the type of the *variable*.

Answer (score 2):

At compile time A.greet() is not accessible.

Hence does not compile.

For overriding, the method must be accessible at compile time, but the decision to call the method is done at runtime.